# Internal Tomcat REST calls to localhost from inside Docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile that runs a Tomcat 7 web server with two REST APIs, a PostgreSQL database, and a Django site on Apache. *(I know that best practices suggest running these as separate containers, but I wanted to package the whole system as one container for usability by non-devs).*

One of my REST API calls the other REST API through the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/rest2/insert`. However, in `bridge mode` in Docker, `localhost` refers to the host, not the container.

I have tried hardcoding the container ip `172.17.0.2` but I still get a `Connection Refused` error.

I assume this will be a problem for the `localhost` PostgreSQL connection from `rest1` as well. What are my options?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `localhost` should always refer to the network context where the container is running.  With (normal) bridged networking, **localhost is not the physical system**, it is the container itself.

Comment: I must have misunderstood this. If that is the case, shouldn't I be able to connect from one REST service to the other with `localhost`?

Comment: Once you decide to move your application to containers you should forget about "localhost". It will only cause you trouble. It is worth to take the time and change the settings and get rid of "localhost" references. For the same reason do not use IP's. Use  container names: these are the ones you control and can change quickly at any time.

Comment: Can I reference them the same way in my rest calls? Sorry for the repeated questions, still new to dockerization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `Connection Refused` error was caused by a lack of memory from Docker. I increased the memory limit and everything was fine. Hopefully this will help someone struggling in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you do put them together in the same container, then localhost should be correct.

use `ps -e` to check if they have been started.